# solr select with 2 fields

Tags: curl, solr

I would like to execute a combined search where zygosity and variant content values match with my specific query.

Considering part of my schema:

```
"fields":[{
            "name":"id",
            "type":"int",
            "indexed":true,
            "stored":true},
          {
            "name":"variant",
            "type":"text_ws",
            "indexed":true,
            "stored":false},
          {
            "name":"zygosity",
            "type":"text_ws",
            "indexed":true,
            "stored":false}],
```

I get zero docs found with the following failed selects:

First try: using (+)

```
curl urlPath/solr/collection/select?q=+variant:"1:28898383:A>T" +zygosity:"het"&wt=json&indent=true&debugQuery=true&rows=100000
```

Second try: fq

```
curl urlPath/solr/collection/select?q=variant:"1:28898383:A>T"fq=zygosity:'het'&wt=json&indent=true&debugQuery=true&rows=100000
```

Example Response:

```
<response>
<lst name="responseHeader"><int name="status">0</int><int name="QTime">1</int><lst name="params"><str name="q">+zygosity:het +variant:(1\:22165566\:G&gt;A)</str></lst></lst><result name="response" numFound="0" start="0"></result>
</response>
```

And many others...

So what am I doing wrong here?

To be sure if I select only zygosity I get 9 docs found!

```
curl urlPath/solr/collection/select?q=zygosity:*&wt=json&indent=true&debugQuery=true&rows=100000

<response>
<lst name="responseHeader"><int name="status">0</int><int name="QTime">0</int><lst name="params"><str name="q">zygosity:het</str></lst></lst><result name="response" numFound="9" start="0">...</result>
</response>
```

but if I select only variant, zero doc returns to me

```
curl urlPath/solr/collection/select?q=variant:"1:28898383:A>T"&wt=json&indent=true&debugQuery=true&rows=100000

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
<lst name="responseHeader"><int name="status">0</int><int name="QTime">1</int><lst name="params"><str name="q">variant:(1\:28898383\:A&gt;T)</str></lst></lst><result name="response" numFound="0" start="0"></result>
</response>
```

Any suggestion why select is not considering 2 fields? or why search only variant field does not return anything?

Answer (score 0):

I would guess the problem is in the encoding of the parameters. I would try with something like this:

```
curl http://localhost:8983/solr/your-core/select?q=variant%3Avariant-value%20AND%20zygosity%3Ahet
```

Notice that "%3A" is the encoded value for ":" so `q` value in human-readable would form would say:

```
q=variant:variant-value AND zygosity:het
```

I suspect the fact that your `variant` value has a colon and an greater-than symbol as part of the value is part of the problem since those characters might be tricky to get encoded properly.